# Use different view in Django if the url contains specific character

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have this view:

```
def url_redirect(request,id):
        url = get_object_or_404(Url,short_id=id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url.httpurl)
```

and these urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(ur'^(?P<id>.*)$', views.url_redirect),

]
```

Basically what it does is redirecting from http://127.0.0.1:8000/XYZ to a different site

Now i would like to have a possibility to use a different view if the url varies slightly by adding "!" character, i.e :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/!XYZ

So whenever i use this url it will do something else than redirecting.

Any idea how can i do this?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: if '!' in id do something ?

Comment: Not sure if "!" should be in <id> because i query the db with it ,and there  should be no objects that contain it.

Comment: @sztyrymytyry If you know the `!` is there, you can strip it off and query the db with the remainder...

Comment: Exclamation marks are converted into `%21` in urls' so its not really ever going to work, why do you want to do this? why cant you just use a different url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deal with it in the same view, leave the `urls` as they are and change the view:

```
def url_redirect(request,id):
    if id.startswith('!'):
        id = id[1:]
        # do whatever you want with id
    else:
        url = get_object_or_404(Url,short_id=id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url.httpurl)
```

Comment: Hi!  url(ur'^!(?P<id>.*)$', views.diff_view) doesn't work :S still tries to use views.url_redirect. However the startswith is what I am looking for so thanks very much!

Comment: Exclamation marks are shown as %21 in urls' so its not really ever going to work

Comment: @Sayse Aw, can you then try to match the `%21` url-encoded version?

Comment: @schwobaseggl - You could, but then you're matching against an ugly looking url